# Помогите настроить xDebug

Tags: php, centos, phpstorm, xdebug

Добрый день.

Есть машина (хост-машина), на которой установлена виртуальная машина. 
На виртуальной машине стоит CentOS 6 + apache + nginx:
apache крутится на 8080 порте, nginx на 80 порте.

конфигурация хоста (который хочу дебажить) apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin alex@troom.ru
    ServerName tests.local
    ServerAlias www.tests.local
    DocumentRoot /home/httpdocs/tests.local/www
    <Directory /home/httpdocs/tests.local/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /home/httpdocs/tests.local/log/apache_error_log
    CustomLog /home/httpdocs/tests.local/log/apache_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

конфигурация хоста (который хочу дебажить) nginx:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name tests.local www.tests.local;
        access_log  /home/httpdocs/tests.local/log/nginx_access_log main;

        # Не кеширую статику
        #location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|avi|flv|swf|js|doc|docx|rtf|pdf|xls|xlsx|rar|zip|tbz|7z|tgz|tar|gz|bz2|ppt|txt|mid|midi|wav|exe|ttf|eof|svg|woff)$ {
        #                root /home/httpdocs/tests.local/www/;
        #                access_log off;
        #                expires 30d;
        #                               add_header Cache-Control public;
        #}

        location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny  all;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            log_not_found off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Connection close;
            proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
            proxy_pass_header Content-Disposition;
            proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
}
```

настройки xDebug, /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
```

и php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.auto_trace=off
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug_log.log"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
```

На хост-машине IDE PHPStorm, настройки xDebug:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Google Chrome установлено расширение xDebug helper.

При попытке дебага ничего не происходит, в лог xDebug пишется:

```
Log opened at 2015-11-02 12:05:34
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2015-11-02 12:05:34
```

Понимаю, что скорее всего проблема с nginx, но что именно ему не хватает - не знаю.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Спасибо, правда успел уже сам разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
> ```

Вы открыто задаете хост, к которому надо подключаться (и это - локалхост, т.е. виртуалка). Вам же нужен внешний хост, укажите его айпишник в той сети, к которой принадлежит виртуалка. Автоматический connect back скорее всего всё равно не будет работать, потому что будет видеть айпишник проксирующего нгинкса (зачем вам вообще нужен апач - отдельный вопрос, его смело можно выкинуть).

Comment: >> (зачем вам вообще нужен апач - отдельный вопрос, его смело можно выкинуть).

Вы имеете в виду, что лучше использовать nginx + php-fpm, вместо nginx + apache?

Comment: @Александр да, апач медленный, да и mod-php не особо оптимальная штуковина

Comment: А с .htaccess-ами и подобными вещами проблем не будет? 
p.s: Я просто не очень знаком с php-fpm.

Comment: @Александр, там немного другая ситуация, но поверьте, .htaccess на самом деле не нужен и является зловредной штукой (особенно с точки зрения оптимизации выполнения запросов). В nginx конфиг ведется (чаще всего) в одном файле на хост, и через некоторое время так становится удобней. Само подключение php-fpm обычно занимает строчек пять - гораздо меньше, чем конфиг текущей прокси.

Answer (score 0):

Пока не могу комментировать. IP указан локальный. У вас веб-сервер и браузер на одной машине? Если веб-сервер запущен внутри виртуальной машины, а браузер в родительской системе, то IP у них разные.