# не работает xdebug в phpStorm vagrant apache2

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm, xdebug, vagrant

перерыл кучу мануалов при всех различных настройках при которых все должно работать при отправке запроса сервер ~2 минуты ждет после отправки заголовка а потом выдает страницу все брейки игнорируются, в шторме ничего не происходит, в phpinfo xdebug подключен вот одна из последних статей http://www.magekey.net/2016/03/13/installer-xdebug-sur-phpstorm-vagrant/

win10

vagrant - PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

20-xdebug.ini

xdebug.remote_enable = on

xdebug.remote_connect_back = on

xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"

в xDebug helper как с IDE key "vagrant" так и с "PHPSTORM"

Comment: Гляньте сюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480402/191482   вдруг поможет..... `idekey` в принципе не нужен

Comment: маппинг в phpStorm настроен сервер указан на 80 порт, настройки с данного поста не помогают, прослушка включена, так же 2 минуты и отображает страницу в ide тишина (так только при включенном расширении в хроме, иначе все быстро отображает)

Comment: А что за расширение и зачем оно вам нужно? Там и без него все дебажится на ура

Comment: [xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.auto_trace=off
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug_log.log"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp" 
-

Автоматический connect back не работал из за прокси, указав ip напрямую все заработало помог коментт http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463219/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-xdebug?answertab=active#tab-top